# Cannot create two CGPathAddArc on the same CGMutablePathRef

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cgpath

I'm trying to understand why i'm seeing only one of mine `CGPathAddArc`.

Code :

```
  var r: CGRect = self.myView.bounds
 var lay: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        var path: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
        CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 30, 30, 30, 0, (360 * CGFloat(M_PI))/180, true    )
        CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 70, 30, 30, 0, (360 * CGFloat(M_PI))/180, true    )

        CGPathAddRect(path, nil, r2)
 CGPathAddRect(path, nil, r)
        lay.path = path
        lay.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        self.myView.layer.mask = lay
```

result :

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you push down the command key and click on CGPathAddArc function, you will see documentation.

```
/* Note that using values very near 2π can be problematic. For example,
   setting `startAngle' to 0, `endAngle' to 2π, and `clockwise' to true will
   draw nothing. (It's easy to see this by considering, instead of 0 and 2π,
   the values ε and 2π - ε, where ε is very small.) Due to round-off error,
   however, it's possible that passing the value `2 * M_PI' to approximate
   2π will numerically equal to 2π + δ, for some small δ; this will cause a
   full circle to be drawn.

   If you want a full circle to be drawn clockwise, you should set
   `startAngle' to 2π, `endAngle' to 0, and `clockwise' to true. This avoids
   the instability problems discussed above. */
```

Setting `startAngle` to 0, `endAngle` to 2π, and `clockwise` to true will
draw nothing. If you want a full circle to be drawn clockwise, you should set
       `startAngle` to 2π, `endAngle` to 0, and `clockwise` to true. So that you can see all circles.

Comment: Wow, I never thought it'll be associated to the angles, Thank you so much! Got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is *debug*. How? Well, when in doubt, your first step should be to *simplify*. In this case, you should start by testing your code outside the context of a mask and a fill rule. When you do, you'll see that the arcs are in fact both present. I ran this reduced version of your code:

```
    let lay = CAShapeLayer()
    lay.frame = CGRectMake(20,20,400,400)
    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 30, 30, 30, 0, 
        (360 * CGFloat(M_PI))/180, true)
    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 70, 30, 30, 0, 
        (360 * CGFloat(M_PI))/180, true)
    lay.path = path
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(lay)
```

And this is what I got:

[image]

As you can see, both arcs are present. So your results must be due to some complication beyond the drawing of the arcs.

If we add the fill rule...

```
    lay.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
```

...we get this:

[image]

And if we introduce the mask element...

```
    // self.view.layer.addSublayer(lay)
    self.view.layer.mask = lay
```

...we get this:

[image]

Thus, using basic tests, you should be able to convince yourself of what this part of your code does. You can now introduce more and more of your *actual* code until you start getting undesirable results, and then you'll know what's causing the problem.

Comment: Awesome matt. Thank you so much! I'll check again whats wrong with my code than :)

Comment: Hey matt! I've understood why it didn't work + why i couldn't reproduce your code, It has to do with the angles, As you said - the code is fine, But if the angles aren't calculated properly, it's causes the path not be drawn. Check @gabbler answer :) Thank you!